# Focus a field after validation error on Laravel project with Livewire and AlpineJs

Tags: javascript, laravel, focus, laravel-livewire, alpine.js

Hello i need to focus first field of ErrorBag, I am using Livewire component form and because Livewire send XHR request every input change to update the DOM it will be focused every time on XHR response without submitting the form and it's not what I need, I am using also Alpine Js in the same project and I want focus it with Javascript but I don't know if it is possible to watch a property changes.

```
function app(){

return {

    errorBag: {!! json_encode(array_keys($errors->getMessages())) !!},
    

    focusField()
    {
     if(this.errorBag.length > 0)
      {
        fieldError = Array.from(document.getElementsByName(errorBag[0]));
        fieldError[0].focus({preventScroll:false});
      }
    }
}

}
```

In example i want initialize the Alpine component with x-data="app()" and then i want trigger focusField() function if the errorBag property changes to focus only once the field invalid for every form submit.
Thanks for your help

Comment: Your code has syntax errors, are you sure everything has been copied correctly?

Comment: I've updated the code, now you will not receive syntax errors.

Answer (score 1):

Solved myself

```
          <div
            x-data="
            { 
              'errors': {{ json_encode(array_keys($errors->getMessages())) }},
              focusField(input){
                  fieldError = Array.from(document.getElementsByName(input));
                  if(fieldError.length > 0){
                    fieldError[0].focus({preventScroll:false});
                  }
              },
            }
            "
            x-init="() => { $watch('errors', value => focusField(value[0])) }"
        >
        </div>
```

Properties in function app() are not updated,but in x-data object it works perfect.

Comment: Thanks! I get `Alpine Error: "SyntaxError: expected expression, got '}'"` from this. Any idea why?

Answer (score 0):

FWIW I didn't really like this and instead use standard validation with:

```
use Illuminate\Validation\Validator;
    
class ContactForm extends Component
{
    public $name;
    public $email;
 
    protected $rules = [
        'name' => 'required|min:6',
        'email' => 'required|email',
    ];

    public $errors = [];
 
    public function submit()
    {
        $this->withValidator(function (Validator $validator) {
            $validator->after(function ($validator) {
                $this->errors = $validator->failed();
            });
        })->validate();
        ...
    }

}
```

Then in blade:

```
<div 
x-data="{
errors: @entangle('errors'),
focusError() {
    es = Object.keys(this.errors);
    if (es.length == 0) { return }
    $focus.focus(document.getElementsByName(es[0])[0]);
  }
}"
x-init="$watch('errors', value => focusError())"
>
```

You could also scroll to element instead of or in addition to focus.